# Inserting data from a text file directly to an sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

for example if i had a text file in the following format

```
A
B
C
D
E
.
.
.
```

and an sql table calld `table` with column called `letters`

i want to insert each value in the text file to the column `letters`, is it possible to do this directly from SQL Server without using any other programming language?

also is it possible to specify a seperator for the values like `"/"` or `"#"`? in case the the text format was `A/B/C/D` or `A#B#C#D`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, exactly. Use [**BULK INSERT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) can resolve your issue.